# pythonでXMLを操作でのエラーが発生と文字化け①

Tags: python, xml

以下のようなXMLファイルとpythonのファイルで実行しようとしているのですが、エラーが発生しどうすればエラーが消えるのかわかりません。また、文字化けも起きているのですが対処方法はありますか。（UTF-8を使用している）

**エラーコード（実行結果）**

```
C:\Users\g21125\python_xml_ex>python attribute-access.py
パン
縺ｮ辷ｶ隕ｪ縺ｯ
C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py:693: UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif value != attr.value:
謔滄｣ｯ

C:\Users\g21125\python_xml_ex>
```

**sample.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipe name="パン" preparations-time="5分" cokking-time="3時間">
    <dish>基本的なパン</dish>
    <material quantity='3' unit='カップ'>小麦粉</material>
    <material quantity='0.25' unit='オンス'>イースト</material>
    <material quantity='1.5' unit='カップ'>水</material>
    <material quantity='1' unit='ティースプーン'>食塩</material>
    <point>
        <process>全ての材料を一緒にして混ぜます。</process>
        <process>十分にこねます。</process>
        <process>布で覆い、暖かい部屋で1時間そのままにしておきます。</process>
        <process>もう一度こねます。</process>
        <process>パン焼きの容器に入れます。</process>
        <process>布で覆い、暖かい部屋で1時間そのままにしておきます。</process>
        <process>オーブンに入れて温度を180℃にして30分間焼きます。</process>
    </point>
</recipe>
```

**attribute-access.py**

```python
# coding: utf-8
# タグの属性にアクセス

from xml.dom import minidom

# sample.xmlファイルを読み込む
xdoc = minidom.parse("sample.xml")

# recipe タグの0番目の要素を取得
recipe_element = xdoc.getElementsByTagName("recipe")[0]

# name 属性を取得して表示
print(recipe_element.getAttribute("name"))

print("の父親は")

# name 属性を変更
recipe_element.setAttribute("name", "悟飯")

# 再度 name 属性を表示
print(recipe_element.getAttribute("name"))
```

**実行結果(正常終了の場合)**

```
パン
の父親は
悟飯
```

Comment: 「pythonでXMLを操作でのエラーが発生と文字化け 1 〜 3」に掲載されているコードは Python3 での実行を前提として書かれたものなのではないでしょうか？ Python3 で実行すると、全てエラーなく正常終了します。

Comment: 今になって気が付いたのですが、[Python で XML 操作](http://tmlife.net/programming/python/python-xml-minidom.html) のコードを使っているのでしょうか？ このブログの別のエントリ [Python を始めよう!!](http://tmlife.net/programming/python/python-lets-begin.html) を読むと、Python 3.2 をインストールしていますので、やはり Python3 を前提としたコードの様です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あまり状況が分からないのですが。Python 2.xを使っていて、ソースコードがUTF-8で書かれていて、Windowsの通常のコマンドプロンプト上で実行しているとすれば、コマンドプロンプトがUTF-8を表示できないから文字化けしているのでは？

print("の父親は") → print(u"の父親は")

recipe_element.setAttribute("name", "悟飯") も、unicode文字列に変えるとエラーが消えるかもしれません(別のエラーが出るかもしれません。そのときはすみません)
recipe_element.setAttribute("name", u"悟飯")

参考: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nullpobug/20110706/1309934555